# How to update two MySQL tables with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I Have 2 tables in my db that each have a column named Catergory.

```
Categories Table -
id | category_name
1  : basic
2  : midlevel
3  : highlevel
4  : profesional

Product Table - 
id | product | category_name
1  : adsl 1G : basic
2  : adls 2G : midlevel
3  : adsl 3G : highlevel
4  : adsl 4G : profesional
```

When i update the *category_name* in the `categories` table i would like to change it in the `Products` table as well, but i am not sure on how to do this.

I couldnt find and answer because i dont know how to phrase it correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

What my update.php looks like now:

```
     db_update("UPDATE category SET 
    `category_name` = '".$_POST['category_name']."'
     WHERE category_id = '".$id."'");
```

what is should look like:???

{code here}

Note: "FIXED - I forgot to send my old value to the save.php file so the $id never knew what to update".

Comment: Are the category names supposed to be the same in both tables? If not, can you explain a bit more what needs to happen on an update? Maybe give an example?

Comment: Use a join, and update fields in both table.

Comment: You should simply give reference key (category_id) into product table..that would be batter.

Comment: @Konerak: How to apply JOIN in current table structure?

Comment: I edited it a bit to look better! I have an admin area where i can edit both tables but separately. The products admin area pulls a categories selection from the categories table so if i add more categories to the categories table they will be available under products. But i need to be able to change a categories as well at a later stage and it needs to then  update it in the products table as well. Hope i explained in a way you understand.

Comment: @Chandresh: I am hoping the question asker knows. I am thinking to join on category_name, but a foreign key pointing to a primary key would be better. That's why I propose he does such, in my answer below.

Comment: @JohanPretorius: Can you please make change in product table from category_name to category_id?

Comment: Now i need to update Categories and have it Update the categories in Products. And for some reason i cant get it to work.

Comment: You could a TRIGGER so you don't have to write any extra PHP code. Just update one of the tables.

Comment: Haven't though of using a TRIGGER yet thanks @Fredrik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just run two queries changing both names:

```
<?php
mysql_query("UPDATE categories SET category_name='" . $catname . "' WHERE category_name='basic'");
mysql_query("UPDATE product SET category_name='" . $catname . "' WHERE category_name='basic'");
?>
```

If you want to do it in one string you can do this with multiple queries, a joined query or a stored procedure.

Multiple queries in one string:

```
<?php
    mysql_query("
        mySqlQuery(UPDATE categories SET category_name='" . $catname . "' WHERE category_name='basic';)
        mySqlQuery(UPDATE product SET category_name='" . $catname . "' WHERE category_name='basic';)
    ");
?>
```

Joined query:

```
<?php
mysql_query("
    UPDATE `product`,`categories`
    SET `product`.`category_name` = '" . $catname . "',
        `categories`.`category_name` = '" . $catname . "'
    WHERE `items`.`id` = '" . $catname . "'
");
?>
```

If none of the above work I suggest changing your tables so there isn't a matching name but a matching ID.

You'll get the following:

```
Categories Table -
id | category_name
1  : basic
2  : midlevel
3  : highlevel
4  : profesional

Product Table - 
id | category_ID | product
1  : 1           : adsl 1G
2  : 2           : adls 2G
3  : 3           : adsl 3G
4  : 3           : adsl 4G
```

Comment: Updating them with 2 different sets wont help me i have tried this, i need one string to update both tables. Essentially if i update Categories Table it needs to update Products Table with the new formatted category.

Comment: I added an other solution to the answer. That one is one string.

Comment: Thanks this is working now! I am using a joined query as you suggested.

Comment: Out of curiosity which one are you using?

Comment: I am using the "Joined query:" and made some small changes to my database. I am testing everything now. Will add an update as soon as it is running smoothly.

Comment: I just forgot to send my old value to the save string, so my query never knew what to update. Dont know why i didnt look at that first. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DaniëlVoogsgerd - In the above answer where you use matching ID's instead of names, what happens to the values of `product 1` & `product 2` if you completely delete `basic` & `midlevel` from the categories table?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Categories t1 
JOIN Product t2 ON (t1.category_name  = t2.category_name ) 
SET t1.category_name = ?
    t1.category_name = ?
WHERE t1.id = ?
```

But you are feeling yourself that your data model is ugly. It might be better to de-normalize...

Have the product table refer to the category table:

```
Product Table - 
id | product | category_ID

Categories Table -
id | category_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you link your products table to your categories table by use of the category table's 'id' field. This way you will be linked to the same category and can change the category name without fear of breaking anything else, as you will still be linking to the same category id.

Consider the following:

```
Categories Table - id | category_name 1 : basic 2 : midlevel 3 : highlevel 4 : profesional

Product Table - id | product | category_id l : adsl 1G : basic 2 : adls 2G : midlevel 3 : adsl 3G : highlevel 4 : adsl 4G : profesional
```

The way you are currently doing it will seemingly be very hard to maintain, as you may need to add another column in future that uses a category in some way, and having to keep changing the 'category_name' column for all of those tables will probably end up very messy. By linking to the id, you can make any change you like in the category table without worrying that you will lose the link to any other tables(which is what will happen with the current tables).

Edit: You can get any information about categories by use of joins such as INNER JOINS. This will be a better approach, I think. Also, consider adding a relationship between the 'category_id' column in the products table with the 'id' column in the category table. This will ensure that a category will not just get deleted while there are still products linked to it.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you have a relation like products and categories which you mentioned it is always better to have the structure as follows :

```
Categories Table -
id | category_name
1  : basic
2  : midlevel
3  : highlevel
4  : profesional

Product Table - 
id | product | category_id
1  : adsl 1G : 1
2  : adls 2G : 2
3  : adsl 3G : 3
4  : adsl 4G : 4
```

So whenever you need to show the category name for a product, you can do it by using joins.
So this change will enable you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you've got `category_name` in both tables, it seems pointless as far as I can see.

Ideally your table structure should be like this:

```
Categories Table -
id | category_name
1  : basic
2  : midlevel
3  : highlevel
4  : profesional

Product Table - 
id | product | category_id
1  : adsl 1G : 1
2  : adls 2G : 2
3  : adsl 3G : 3
4  : adsl 4G : 4
```

This allows you to change the name of the category in the categories table without needing to change anything in the products table.

All you then need to do is join the 2 tables in your SELECT query, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM `categories`,`products` WHERE `categories`.`id`=`products`.`category_id`
```

Comment: I have it in both tables because they are two different things that i need at the end of the day. I need categories on its own because there will be a lot and they will get listed separately. But there will be products for each category that needs to list below them.

Comment: This is working, just a simple question. When i send it to my "update.php" how will i use it to update my SET?

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it helps

```
$query = "UPDATE tblname SET colname = '$var';";
$query .="UPDATE tblname1 SET colname1 = '$var1';";
/* execute multi query */
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
             printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        /* print divider */
        if (mysqli_more_results($conn)) {
            printf("");
        }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($conn));
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Im going to up vote this since its right, but a few years to late! lol! I have changed my way of coding significantly since i did this. But thank you for keeping this thread alive.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I used to encounter with this problem as well. Here the clue! Please try this,

```
$sql = "UPDATE categorise c, product p SET category_name='$cate' ";
$sql = $sql. "WHERE c.id=p.id AND c.id like "."\"".$cate."\" ";
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score -1):

Simple use the code below, hope this works for you.

```
          $sql = "UPDATE productSET category_name='$catname' WHERE id='$coode';";
          $sql .= "UPDATE categoriesSET category_name='".$catname."' WHERE category_name='$category_name';";
           if (mysqli_multi_query($db, $sql)) {
              do {
                  /* store first result set */
                  if ($result = mysqli_store_result($db)) {
                      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                        echo "Success";
                      }
                      mysqli_free_result($result);
                  }
                  /* print divider */
                  if (mysqli_more_results($db)) {
                      printf("");
                  }
              } while (mysqli_next_result($db));
          }
```

Comment: You hope the code works?  Have you tested it to work?

Comment: Yes, I had a running with the same issue and it worked for me yesterday.